# How to access Github organization package feed (After moving from personal account) Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, github, nuget

I created a a Github package under my personal account and was able to access the Nuget feed via Visual Studio using a Personal Access Token. Now I have created a new organization and moved my Repo to this new organization.

I notice now that now Nuget Package Manager finds no packages on this feed anymore (even after updating the URL to point to where it lives now).

My builds(on Github Actions) can still build using my Personal Access Token but how am I able to actually access the packages in Visual Studio after the move?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry its been a bit hectic. I will use your advice over the weekend and get back to you.

Comment: Well. Any feedback will be expected:)

Comment: any update about this issue, please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the new github repos into nuget package source with new your organization and Personal Access Token again.

If you have `nuget.exe` cli, you could run:

```
nuget source Add -Name "<name>" -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<new organization>/index.json" -UserName <new organization> -Password <token>
```

Please refer to [this document](https://milangatyas.com/Blog/Detail/9/publish-nuget-package-to-github-packages#:%7E:text=To%20do%20so%2C%20go%20to,credentials%20for%20the%20package%20store.).

**Besides**, you have to use [packageSourceCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials) for your new github nuget feed.

Close VS, enter `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`,

add like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  ......

    <packageSources>
      .....
      <add key="MyRepo" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<new organization>/index.json" />
    </packageSources>

    <!-- Used to store credentials -->
    <packageSourceCredentials>

      <MyRepo>
        <add key="Username" value="new organization" />
        <add key="Password" value="token" />
      </MyRepo>

    </packageSourceCredentials>

 
</configuration>
```